# Kernel of the Derivative linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V = C^{\inf}(a,b)$ the space of all functions that have derivatives of every order in $(a,b)$.Let $D:V→V$ the derivative.

I need to find the kernel of $D$ and $D^n$ (because $D$ is an endomorphism of $V$, $D^n=D \circ D \circ\ ... \ \circ D$)

I have found that the kernel of $D$ is $\{f\in V :f'(x)=0\}$, or every constant function in $V$. I think the dimension of $ker(D)$ should be $1$ right?

I also think that the dimension of $ker(D^n)$ should be $n$ ,but I need help formalizing these results. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B=\{1, x, x^2,...,x^{(n-1)}\}$ is a basis for $ker(D^n)$